# Ask for Administative priviliges despite using sudo?

Tags: centos, sudo, rights

I am trying to unzip a file with the following command but get a privilige error.

```
-bash-4.2$ unzip traccar-linux-*.zip && ./traccar.run
Archive:  traccar-linux-64-latest.zip
replace traccar.run? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: A
  inflating: traccar.run
  inflating: README.txt
Administrative privileges required for this archive (use su or sudo)
```

My user is having sudo 'rights'

```
-bash-4.2$ sudo -l -U gc_admin
[sudo] password for gc_admin:
Matching Defaults entries for gc_admin on agitated-lewin:
    !visiblepw, always_set_home, match_group_by_gid, always_query_group_plugin,
    env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE KDEDIR LS_COLORS",
    env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE",
    env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES",
    env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE",
    env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY",
    secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin

User gc_admin may run the following commands on agitated-lewin:
    (ALL) ALL

-bash-4.2$ groups gc_admin
gc_admin : psacln wheel
```

For some reason even with the sudo command, I am not allowed to unzip?

```
-bash-4.2$ sudo unzip traccar-linux-*.zip && ./traccar.run
[sudo] password for gc_admin:
Archive:  traccar-linux-64-latest.zip
replace traccar.run? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: A
  inflating: traccar.run
  inflating: README.txt
Administrative privileges required for this archive (use su or sudo)
```

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: Who is the owner of the path/file?

Comment: -bash-4.2$ stat -c "%U %G" /var/www/vhosts/geoclaim.nl/httpdocs

gc_admin psaserv`

So my user (gc_admin) owns the path.

Comment: What are the privileges on the file? Does it have read privileges?

Answer (score 0):

Think I ansewred it myself.

The command that i was trying to use (unzip traccar-linux-*.zip && ./traccar.run) consists of two parts. When run seperatly, both with their own sudo command, it al worked fine.